# Configuring auto-completion in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

What needs to be done so methods of a variable appear after entering a point? 
Moreover, if the variable is explicitly defined as a string, prompts appear.

[image: No methods for variable]

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, the IDE has no way of knowing beforehand what type `str` will be. Even though the name association may seem logical for a human programmer, this may be a false friend and still have a completely different type.

However, as soon as the IDE has a clue - *either* provided by you *or* by the logical programming flow - code completion will start to work. So:

#### Provide clues using [JSDoc annotations](https://jsdoc.app/)

[image]

This is a good practice when writing software anyway, **especially** in loose-typed languages such as JavaScript or PHP <7 - as it will make your life (and those of programmers invoking your code) a whole lot easier.

When working with libraries, you may sometimes need to provide VS Code with a [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) to enable it to parse the JSDoc of file it didn't discover in your project workspace.

---

Otherwise VS Code (like any modern IDE) is perfectly capable of

#### Type Inference from logical flow

[image]